# Can anyone identify this 1920's era biplane bomber?

Tags: military, aviation-history, aircraft-identification

What is the aircraft in this photo?  My great uncle is in the back row second to the right. He was born in 1900, so I think this photo is from around 1920. I think he was based at Kelly Field in San Antonio, TX. Does anyone know more about the aircraft or the group in the photo?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a De Havilland DH-4 variant based on how the struts protrude from the body. Particularly this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4856.jpg. For other references, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.4 or https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/de-havilland-dh-4/nasm_A19190051000 or https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/197397/de-havilland-dh-4/

Comment: I keep envisioning the bombardier holding that in his lap and heaving it over the side at the right point. _Probably_ not the way it was done, though.

Comment: Next ASE question-- could the bomb on the photo really be carried by that plane?  Looks a bit oversized!

Answer (score 10):

The close proximity between the pilot cockpit (the front cockpit) and the observer-gunner cockpit (the rear cockpit) suggests a [Airco/ De Haviland DH-9A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A).  On the related [DH-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.4), the two cockpits were much further apart, with a fuel tank in between them.

Addendum-- "1,538 DH-4s were modified in 1919-1923 to DH-4Bs by moving the pilot's seat back and the now unpressurized gas tank forward, correcting the most serious problems in the DH-4 design."  -from the [National Museum of the United States Air Force website](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/197397/de-havilland-dh-4/) (link previously shared by ASE contributor JonSG).  Since the DH-9A was not widely used in the US, the aircraft is in fact most likely a DH-4B.